# How to use message handlers in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, http, .net-6.0, message-handlers

I need to add a custom header to each http request. To do so, I want to use a message handler and override SendAsync() method like so:

```
    public class RequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly ICorrelationIdAccessor _correlationIdAccessor;

        public RequestHandler(ICorrelationIdAccessor correlationIdAccessor)
        {
            _correlationIdAccessor = correlationIdAccessor;
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("CorrelationId", _correlationIdAccessor.GetCorrelationId());

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

How can I register this new message handler in Program.cs using .NET 6 ?

What I did for now, is to create a **HttpConfiruration** object and add the **RequestHandler** to the **MessageHandlers collection**, but I don't know how to register it to the **builder**:

```
var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestHandler());
```

Any suggestions on how to do this, or any other ways on how to add a custom header to all the HTTP requests are welcomed.

Thank you !

Comment: is it .NET Core or framework ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can do it for named/typed `HttpClient` created by `IHttpClientFactory` (see [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#consumption-patterns), [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#multiple-ways-to-use-ihttpclientfactory)):

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<SomeServiceUsingHttpClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<RequestHandler>();
```

See [outgoing request middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#outgoing-request-middleware) part of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you also seek to add the DelegatingHandler to all of your HttpClients constructed by the IHttpClientFactory, then the following will achieve that.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
        {
            builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(builder.Services.GetRequiredService<RequestHandler>());
        });
    });
builder.Services.AddScoped<RequestHandler>();
```

In the code snippet, all HttpClients will use the RequestHandler as a MessageHandler, and finally remember to add the RequestHandler to the ServiceCollection as well.

Comment: It's not working. The ConfigureAll throws and error with the 'The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.'

Comment: @Azazulhaq works just fine. Just checked it out again on .NET 8 as well for a project. Check here for reference: https://github.com/jokk-itu/api-template/blob/main/Api/Program.cs